# Tensorflow - memory leak (or something) when reading TFRecord

Tags: python, machine-learning, memory-leaks, tensorflow

i'm working on some CNN model in tensorflow, but i have a problem related to the reading of my data.

i have a file, a TFRecord file, compressed using GZIP, i want to read the data from this file in batches, and i set up the next code to do so:

```
 def _input_fn( files ):
        print( files )
        thread_count = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
        batch_size = 2 # for debug
        num_epochs = 2 
        min_after_dequeue = 1000

        queue_size_multiplier = thread_count + 3

        filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer( files , num_epochs = num_epochs )

        example_id , encoded_examples = tf.TFRecordReader(
            options = tf.python_io.TFRecordOptions  (
                compression_type= TFRecordCompressionType.GZIP
            )
        ).read_up_to( filename_queue , batch_size)
        features, targets = example_parser(encoded_examples )
        capacity = min_after_dequeue + queue_size_multiplier

        images , labels = tf.train.shuffle_batch(
            [features , targets ] , batch_size , num_threads = thread_count ,
            capacity = capacity , min_after_dequeue = min_after_dequeue ,
            enqueue_many = True 
        )

        return images , labels
```

the usual code for reading TFRecords. then i procced to create the a test graph, not the actual NN, for testing

```
inputs, labels = _inpunt_fn(files )
# the shape of the tensors returned by _input_fn is correct. [batch_size ,150*150*150      ]
ss = inputs + 1 # some computation  
init_op = tf.group(tf.global_variables_initializer(),
                   tf.local_variables_initializer())

sess = tf.Session()

sess.run( init_op  )

coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess=sess, coord=coord)
# i cut some things to make it shorter ... 
while not coord.should_stop():
    sess.run( [ ss ] )
    print(" test ")
```

i run this code and i never get to see the "test" printed. the program crashes my pc. I  use the "top" command to watch the memory usage, and it grows fast until the program and everything in my pc colapses.

The dataset is large. each sample is a  3d matrix ( 150 x 150 x 150 ), and there are a thousand samples. but i'm not ( in theory ) loading it to the memory , i'm reading it in tiny batches, right? , then why this occurs... what is the problem with the way i'm reading the files and how can i fix it.

Thanks beforehand. any insight is welcome.

Comment: You're probably seeing extra memory usage from the internal queues used in the input pipeline. Can you see the same issue if you use tf.data?